# dereferencing a null pointer within typeid

Tags: c++, typeid

While researching a recent question, I came upon the following clause in the '03 standard[1]:

> When typeid is applied to an lvalue
>   expression whose type is a polymorphic
>   class type (10.3), the result refers
>   to a type_info object representing the
>   type of the most derived object (1.8)
>   (that is, the dynamic type) to which
>   the lvalue refers. If the lvalue
>   expression is obtained by applying the
>   unary * operator to a pointer and
>   the pointer is a null pointer value
>   (4.10), the typeid expression throws
>   the bad_typeid exception (18.5.3).

Specifically, I am wondering about the last bit, which provides well defined behavior for the result of dereferencing a null pointer.  As far as I can tell, this is the only time this is done[2].  Specifically, `dynamic_cast<T&>` has no special treatment for this case, and that seems like a much more useful scenario.  Doubly so considering `dynamic_cast<T&>` is already defined as throwing an exception under certain circumstances.

Is there a specific reason that this particular expression was given special treatment?  It seems completely arbitrary, so I am guessing there is some specific use case they had in mind.

---

[1] A similar clause exists in '11, but it refers to glvalue expressions, rather than lvalue expressions.

[2] `delete 0;` and `dynamic_cast<T*>(0)` come close, but in both cases you are dealing with a pointer value, rather than an actual object.

Comment: In the case of `dynamic_cast` there is such provision: 5.2.7/4 *If the value of v is a null pointer value in the pointer case, the result is the null pointer value of type R.* As to why it does not throw, well, `dynamic_cast` has two versions, on pointers it will not throw (rather return 0), while with references it will throw if it cannot perform the conversion.

Comment: @David: I think I misread the previous section; I took that to be an extension of the case where `T` and `v` are the same type.  Looking back, you are likely correct.  However, for the reference case, it remains undefined.  As expected given the rest of the standard.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: You cannot possibly have a *null* reference in a valid program. The only ways to obtain an invalid reference are undefined behaviors, so there is no need for a special provision on what could possibly happen in a program *after* UB has already happened

Comment: @David: Exactly. And yet, `typeid` has a special provision for just that situation.  `Type* p = 0; typeid(*p);` throws `std::bad_typeid`. `Type* p = 0; dynamic_cast<OtherType&>(*p);` is undefined.

Comment: Note that `Type* p = 0; Type& t = *p; typeid(t);` is not covered by this clause.  The second line yields undefined behavior, and all bets are off.  Perhaps my question would have been better worded as "why doesn't dynamic_cast work this way" rather than "why does typeid work this way."  I think its a useful way to define the operation; its a simple check, after all, and certainly useful.

Comment: `typeid` is special in the same way as `sizeof`, they are not regular functions or casts. In the case of `dynamic_cast<R&>(*p)` you are *evaluating `*p`* and *then* applying `dynamic_cast` on the reference. In the case of `typeid` and `sizeof` you are asking about the expression, not the value. The expression is *not evaluated* unless it is a dereference of a non-null pointer, as the expression is never evaluated if the type can be statically inferred by the compiler (non-polymorphic pointer, function call...)

Comment: As of the question: "why does `dynamic_cast` not work this way?" the answer is that it does, when you call `dynamic_cast` on a pointer it will check for null before dereferencing to obtain the dynamic type. The problem is that if YOU dereference the argument, that operation is evaluated *before* it gets to `dynamic_cast`, that is: `dynamic_cast<T&>( *(U*)0 )` is equivalent to `U& u = *(U*)0; dynamic_cast<T&>( u );`, an the undefined behavior is while evaluating the argument.

Comment: @David: Aha.  That the expression fed to `typeid` is not evaluated in the non-polymorphic case is exactly what I was missing.  If it does not evaluate the expression in the general case, not fully evaluating the expression in other cases is much less arbitrary than it initially seemed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Had I paid more attention to the very next clause (5.2.8/3), I would have seen this

> When typeid is applied to an
>   expression other than an lvalue of a
>   polymorphic class type, . . . The expression is
>   not evaluated.

In other words, as with `sizeof` (among others in C++11), the compiler is not meant to actually run the code you pass to `typeid`, it is just supposed to analyze it for behavior.  Unfortunately, unlike `sizeof`, the result sometimes depends on the runtime behavior of the expression due to polymorphic types.

```
Base* p1 = new Derived;
Base* p2 = new Base;
typeid(*p1); //equivalent to typeid(Derived) [assuming Base is polymorphic]
typeid(*p2); //equivalent to typeid(Base)
```

If the expression were completely unevaluated, the compiler could not check the RTTI to see that `p1` is actually pointing to a `Derived` instead of a `Base`.  The standard writers decided to go one step further, however, and stated that if the expression is ultimately a dereference of a pointer type, the compiler should only partially evaluate it.   If the pointer is null, throw `std::bad_typeid` rather than perform the dereference and introduce undefined behavior.

Contrast that with `dynamic_cast`.  The expression passed to `dynamic_cast` is always fully evaluated, the result would make no sense otherwise.  Since the compiler is required to fully evaluate the expression anyhow, it makes no sense to instruct it to stop early and throw an exception.

In short, this is given special treatment in much the same way that `sizeof(*(int*)0)` is given special treatment.  `*(int*)0` isn't meant to be evaluated, so there is no reason to introduce undefined behavior in the first place, even though it looks bad.

Comment: Any quotation from the standard that supports this?

Comment: @Xeo: yes, but I don't have my copy handy so they'll have to wait for the morning. I plan on fleshing this out, I just wanted to get this off the "unanswered" list since David did all the grunt work in comments.

Comment: Okay then, I'm waiting for it. :) Besides, there's always the C++0x FDIS for a quick glance.

Comment: @Xeo: There you go.  Its in the same section in C++11, the wording is just slightly different to account for the extended types of lvalues, as well as all the new types of unevaluated expressions, but the jist is the same.

Comment: You can always use a function call as an argument to `typeid`. If the function is declared to return an lvalue of polymorphic type, the function will have to be called. Which means that in this case the operand expression is, of course, evaluated.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between partial and full evaluation?